# Flutter UI of screen distorted when kill app and load again many times. I am using screen_utills class for get screen size

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I used screen_utill class for my project for flexible UI for all screens. but I am facing an issue with that actually when I kill my app and again try to run the app some times screen gets distorted most of the time it seems like it doesn't load or set a ratio for the device.I am struggling with this issue

```
@override
```

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
ScreenUtil.init();// this is where I initialized.
return MultiBlocProvider(
  providers: [
    BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => abcBloc,
    ),
    BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => defBloc,
    ),
  

  ],
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      FocusScopeNode focusScopeNode = FocusScope.of(context);
   
    },
    child: FutureBuilder(
      future: _initializeSharedPrefs(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
       
          return  MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
         
            theme: ThemeData(
            ..........
                  ),
            
            ),
            initialRoute:'login',
            routes: {
              'login': (context) => LoginScreen(),
            
            },
          );
        } else
     
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

static const Size defaultSize = Size(375, 812);
is already set in the screen_utills class.

Answer (score 0):

The second initialization way seem to give an issue. Try out the first initialization process provided in the documentation.

Wrap the MaterialApp widget in your main.dart file with ScreenUtilInit Widget.

```js
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Set the fit size (Find your UI design, look at the dimensions of the device screen and fill it in,unit in dp)
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: Size(360, 690),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
      builder: () =>
      MaterialApp(
        //... other code
        builder: (context, widget) {
          //add this line
          ScreenUtil.setContext(context);
          return MediaQuery(
            //Setting font does not change with system font size
            data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
            child: widget!,
          );
        },
        theme: ThemeData(
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            //To support the following, you need to use the first initialization method
            button: TextStyle(fontSize: 45. sp)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i did changes as you mentioned but it was giving same issue so now i have changed the approach i am not using screen_util library instead  i use mediaquery.of(context).size 
FOR NOW.